# Add-on Domain with/without HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, addon-domain

I have created a project where i have same code for multiple websites which is running with add on domain and few with sub domain.

Now i have a issue, i have installed SSL certificate and redirect it to https using .htaccess file for one add on domain but because it has same code base SSL has been forced on all the add on domains.

I want SSL to be integrated on specific add on domains.

Answer (score 0):

Place the .htaccess file in the domain you want to have the redirect and create different .htaccess files in sub domain with different rules.

Comment: Hi, It will not work.
I have mentioned that all the domains have same code base and pointed to same folder on server.